# How to convert a pandas dataframe column from object/string to dictionary and then explode that into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe that has a column which is stored as object/string type but in reality it should be a dictionary. Eventually I want to explode this column into multiple columns
Here is a screenshot of the data in excel (the column in question is "capacity")
[image]

This is what I see when I execute dtypes on the pandas dataframe:

```
id                             object
self                           object
name                           object
simpleName                     object
isAutoTiering                    bool
redundancy                     object
usesFlashPools                   bool
vendorTier                     object
isVirtual                        bool
isRaidGroup                      bool
type                           object
capacity                       object
minDiskSpeed                   object
minDiskType                    object
minDiskSize                    object
isCompactionSavingsEnabled       bool
node id                        object
```

Comment: If you put a dict in a dataframe, it will be of type `object` because a dict is an object. Not all objects of course are `dict`s, it may also be of type `str`. If you want to convert from `str` to `dict`, load it with `json`.

Comment: Hi Sampy, please do not post images of your code, post a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead :D.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
values = df.capacity.str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df
```

Comment: I get an Attribute error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'capacity'. Should the df.capacity part be df["capacity"] instead?

Comment: df["capacity"] should work as well. The error says that capacity doesn't exist in df